# The transforms of appended objects change during rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh, transforms, append

I have these teeth objects in a separate blender file that I plan to append to other files when I need them (I append them as "objects" because when I append the mesh they don't seem to show up), but the two times I've tried, the rotation, location, and scale are strange on import, and on render.

[image: In the project]

[image: After the render]

Also, something to note is that the size and rotation of the teeth while working is after resetting the rotation and scale with alt-r and alt-s

another thing to add is that the position of the teeth in this project is the same as how they are in their original file. The numbers involved in their starting/rendered position seem random

Answer (score 1):

After looking through all the details of my project I realized that the teeth objects had one keyframe on a later frame for some reason, and I was editing their transforms on a different frame so the transforms weren't actually applied.